# Windows boot "Starting Windows" hangs

Tags: windows-7

I got a strange error today when I started my computer.
The computers hangs in the "Starting Windows" screen, after a few sec can i hear the windows login sound, but the "Starting Windows" screen never disappears.
Booting in safe mode works completely fine, I would really hate to reinstall windows, so have any one encountered this problem before and have a solution?

Update: Just to make it even more wierd now, i have a tv connected to my computer, and had it on this time i tryed to boot. The tv workes fine and is not primary monitor, where my real monitor just shows the Starting Windows Screen.

I have tryed to play with the MSConfig, disabling all services and such, no luck.

Update2: removing my amd driver, had helped, going to try to reinstall it soon, will post update here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a driver/hard ware issue.

The good news is, your OS is most likely fine per-se, it's just one driver is being a pest!

Try removing all USB devices/drives you don't need and see if the problem persists, including any recently added hardware.

In safe mode, load up MSCONFIG and remove everything which isn't required, if you know what you are doing with it, if not, read up first!